# Cloning an object doesn't work properly in C#

Tags: c#, clone

I'm having trouble with copying an object.

I want to copy *object1* and then make changes to *object2* without changing *object1*.

```
// I'm cloning lower.Rebar object here
upper.Rebar = lower.Rebar.Clone();

// When I make changes to upper.Rebar, lower.Rebar gets changed too.
upper.Rebar.Polyline.Points.RemoveAll(p => p.Y < breaklevel);

// Here is how I'm cloning the lower.Rebar object
public ColumnElevationRebar Clone()
{
    var obj = new ColumnElevationRebar();

    obj.CanBeContinued = CanBeContinued;
    obj.CanBeSpliced = CanBeContinued;
    obj.ConnectionType = ConnectionType;
    obj.SpliceLength = SpliceLength;
    obj.Polyline = Polyline;

    return obj;
}
```

**Definition of the class**

```
public class ColumnElevationRebar
    {
        public ColumnElevationRebar Clone()
        {
            var obj = new ColumnElevationRebar();

            obj.CanBeContinued = CanBeContinued;
            obj.CanBeSpliced = CanBeContinued;
            obj.ConnectionType = ConnectionType;
            obj.SpliceLength = SpliceLength;
            obj.Polyline = Polyline;

            return obj;
        }

        private double splicelength;
        public double SpliceLength
        {
            get { return splicelength; }
            set { splicelength = Arithmetics.Ceiling(value, 100); }
        }

        public RebarConnectionType ConnectionType { get; set; }

        public bool CanBeSpliced;
        public bool CanBeContinued;

        public bool IsSelected;

        public Polyline Polyline { get; set; }

        public double Length
        {
            get { return Arithmetics.Ceiling(Polyline.Length, 100); }
        }
    }


public class Polyline
{
    public Polyline Clone()
    {
        var obj = new Polyline {Points = this.Points};
        return obj;
    }

    public Polyline()
    {
        Points = new List<_2DPoint>();
    }

    public List<_2DPoint> Points { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you add the definition of `ColumnElevationRebar` class?

Comment: Seems that `Polyline` should be *cloned*, not just *assigned*.

Comment: @FelipeOriani I added the definition of the class.

Comment: You mean I also need to define a Clone method for the polyline class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making only a shallow copy of the object. You should clone all non-value type objects, if you need a deep copy. Based on the names, I'm assuming only `Polyline` needs cloning:

```
public ColumnElevationRebar Clone()
{
    var obj = new ColumnElevationRebar();

    obj.CanBeContinued = CanBeContinued;
    obj.CanBeSpliced = CanBeContinued;
    obj.ConnectionType = ConnectionType;
    obj.SpliceLength = SpliceLength;
    obj.Polyline = Polyline.Clone();

    return obj;
}
```

Just define the Clone method in the Polyline object (I don't know the class).

Edit:
You are making the same mistake in your Polyline class, you also need to clone the list:

```
public Polyline Clone()
{
    var obj = new Polyline {Points = new List<_2DPoint>(this.Points)};
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: I did now but it is not working. I added the Polyline class definition to the question.

Comment: Thanks. It was really frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Polyline is a class, not primitive type. If so, create Clone method for Polyline too and use it.

Comment: Should I use the same Cloning method I have used?

Comment: No. You need write new method. As far as I understand, Polyline aggregates an array (or a list) of Points, right? You need create copy of the array in Polyline.Clone method.

Comment: One more question Mark, does this apply to enum types as well?

Comment: No. Enums like other primitive types (Int32, DateTime) can be just copied, not cloned. String is complex type, but it doesn't require cloning too, because it's read-only. Arrays, lists, stacks and other complex types must be cloned.

Comment: By the way it didn't work I don't know why? I'll update the question with the definition of the polyline class.

Comment: var obj = new Polyline {Points = new List<_2DPoint>(this.Points)}; Here will be created new list with same points.